# SpringBoot test immediatley Terminated at SpringBoot + Gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, gradle

I wanna test this code.

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class StudyClassRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    StudyClassRepository studyClassRepository;

    @Test
    public void add(){

        String[] arr = {"Language","Public","Employment","Certificate","Entrance","Etc","Police","Firefighter"};

        for(int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
            StudyClass studyClass = new StudyClass();
            studyClass.setName(arr[i]);
            StudyClass newSC = studyClassRepository.save(studyClass);
            String name = newSC.getName();
            assertEquals(arr[i], name);
        }

    }

}
```

and 'Run Test' for add()

shows this message immediatley

**Process finished with exit code -1**

how to solve this?

Comment: Do you find some error on console? if yes, post it

Comment: Nope, my guess is it's a gradle.bundle setup issue.